# What happens if you raise a normal distribution to a power?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable with normal distribution.

Do $X^2 $, $X^3 $, ..., $X^n$ also have normal distribution?

If so, do they have the same means and variances as X?

Comment: They don't have normal distribution.  But we can compute their density functions, and means, variances.

Comment: If X is standard normal then $X^2$ is chi square with 1 degree of freedom for sure..